# Software for performing what-if scenario on cash flow

Tags: finance, simulation

Is there any recommended software to simulate a what-if scenario for personal cash flow? I tried to use Excel for simple scenarios but my scenarios quickly become unmanageable.

Below is an example of the scenarios to give an idea of the what I'm trying to calculate.

```
Scenario 1:
- stay with company A
- buy house

Scenario 2:
- move to company B
- rent room
- buy house in 4 years
```

Where each of the item is financial events, like:

```
Stay with Company A
- event: paycheck
  recurrence: {payday}
  amount: {base salary}

- event: bonus
  recurrence: {bonus day}
  amount: 15% * 12 * {base salary}

- event: base raise
  recurrence: {raise day}
  action: {base salary} += 10%

- event: promotion
  recurrence: {promotion day}
  action: {base salary} += 50%
```

Comment: I generally do this kind of thing in excel, and generate cash flow ladders for each scenario.   It's fiddly and manual, but it works.  My wife and I have used my spreadsheets for a lot of successful decisions.   Horrible, fiddly, case-specific spreadsheets.  But they work.   I'm upvoting and favoriting your question because I hope someone knows of a generic extensible what-iffer.  If not, maybe I should think about creating one.

Comment: @CPerkins: I had the same story. We (my wife and I) have made some decision based on specific Excel spreadsheet for the scenarios. I was looking for more generic solution since > 1 years ago but cannot find anything, thus the post. On side note, I'm also considering making one as well but still hoping that somebody already made it.